# 柯西 as a character name: can it potentially transliterate as Xi (as in the greek letter)?

Tags: names, transliteration

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly translate the name of a character which is written as `柯西`. I've used a few translation resources, and all of them output `Cauchy`, however, the pronunciation (according to Google Translate) sounds similar to the greek letter Xi, and to make matters worse, this character is a part of a group where every other character's name is also a greek letter. When auto-translated into Chinese, `Xi` yields `席`, however, its pronunciation is nothing like the original name, so I assume that if the author did mean the character to be called Xi, they wouldn't use `席` for that purpose.

So the question I'm having is, can `柯西`, possibly mean `Xi` as a greek letter, which is specifically used as a name?

Comment: 我只听说过柯西-黎曼等式 Cauchy-Riemann Equations ……

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The letters of the Greek alphabet *already* have set transliterations.

For Ξ/ξ, for which the Latin is *xi* (with various pronunciations in English, ranging from /ksiː/ to /zaɪ/), the [standard Chinese version](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B8%8C%E8%85%8A%E5%AD%97%E6%AF%8D/4428067) is [**克西**](https://zh.m.wiktionary.org/zh-hans/%E5%85%8B%E8%A5%BF), which in Mandarin Pinyin is transcribed as `kèxī`. You're right that the sound is very close to the Mandarin for *Cauchy*, with just a difference in tone for one character; but that is different enough to be classified as a different word.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it refers to a Chinese person, "柯西" in modern Chinese almost always means the great mathematician Augustin-Louis Cauchy. Since he is so famous, people would avoid transliterating other names to the same characters, to prevent misunderstanding.

I've never heard of a western person whose last name is "Xi". If there is, I suspect his name would be transliterated as "奚", "熙", etc.

Comment: I see, though the character in question isn't western, but not Chinese either (it's an alien). Also, `柯西` is not necessarily a last name, it's just the name they are known by. But I infer from the answer that the likelihood that it's supposed to mean `Xi` is negligible.